# In Node js how to get certificate Authority Key Identifier (AKI)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, x509certificate, x509

I used the following to get the certificate serial number:

```
var x509 = new jsrsa.X509();
x509.readCertPEM(cert);
serial = x509.getSerialNumberHex();
```

but how do I get its aki?

Answer (score 2):

see: [jsrsasign documentation for Class X509](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/X509.html#getExtAuthorityKeyIdentifier)

```
var x509 = new jsrsa.X509();
x509.readCertPEM(cert); 
aki = x509.getExtAuthorityKeyIdentifier();
```

Comment: I did read the doc and didn't see 'getExtAuthorityKeyIdentifier' in doc, ... I gave it a try anyway and it returned an error : 'x509.getExtAuthorityKeyIdentifier is not a function', Hmmm... may be I will try different version which might have this function.